# How do I match a string in bison grammar?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

How do I match a string in bison grammar? A string that stands for itself like "polySphere" let's say. Will I have to create a token in the .lex file like POLYSPHERE and then use that in bison? Can't I just use the string directly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could recognize the string in bison character by character, eg:

```
polysphere: 'p' 'o' 'l' 'y' 'S' 'p' 'h' 'e' 'r' 'e'
```

but that is rather ineffecient -- generally its much better to recognize the string in the lexer and return a single token

Answer (score 1):

you can't identify a string in your grammar.you will have an error like this :

`multicharacter literal tokens not supported`

you should simply add in your lex

`"polySphere"  { return POLYSPHERE; }`